# Unable to download tlog

Tags: solr, replication

When I activate the replication of a shard via the web interface, the data
will replicate well on the new shard, but once all the data has been
copied, the data will be erased and the synchronization will start again
indefinitely.

When I look in the logs, I have this error:

> `2017-06-29 10:51:39.768 ERROR
>   (recoveryExecutor-3-thread-1-processing-n:X.X.X.X:8983_solr
>   x:collection_shard2_replica2 s:shard2 c:collection r:core_node4)[c:collection
>   s:shard2 r:core_node4 x:collection_shard2_replica2]
>   o.a.s.h.ReplicationHandler Index fetch failed
>   :org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to download
>   tlog.0000000000002131263.1571535118797897728 completely. Downloaded 0!=871
>   at
>
> > org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher$FileFetcher.cleanup(IndexFetcher.java:15>91)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher$FileFetcher.fetch(IndexFetcher.java:1474>)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher$FileFetcher.fetchFile(IndexFetcher.java:>1449)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.downloadTlogFiles(IndexFetcher.java:893)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.fetchLatestIndex(IndexFetcher.java:494)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.fetchLatestIndex(IndexFetcher.java:301)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler.doFetch(ReplicationHandler.java:40>0)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.replicate(RecoveryStrategy.java:219)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.doRecovery(RecoveryStrategy.java:471)
> >     at org.apache.solr.cloud.RecoveryStrategy.run(RecoveryStrategy.java:284)
> >     at
> >     com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(Ins>trumentedExecutorService.java:176)
> >     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> >     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> >     at
> >     org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$ex>ecute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
> >     at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:114>2)
> >     at
> >     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:61>7)
> >     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

I tried to extend the tlog retention time (especially with the
commitReserveDuration option), but it does not work.